# Validando CheckboxList

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Estou usando esse form validation com campos do tipo text. Porém, não to conseguindo de jeito nenhum com checkboxList. Tem como ou alguma maneira de fazer isso? Segue o código abaixo.

```
function form_validation() {
        $("#aspnetForm").validate({
            errorElement: 'span',
            errorClass: 'help-block',
            rules: {
                ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtDataInicioEmissao: {
                    required: true
                },
                ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtDataFimEmissao: {
                    required: true
                },
                ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chkLstOrigem: {
                    checkrequired: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtDataInicioEmissao: {
                    required: "<%= Resources.UIResource.PreenchaOcampo %>"
                },
                ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtDataFimEmissao: {
                    required: "<%= Resources.UIResource.PreenchaOcampo %>"
                }
            },
            highlight: function (element) { // entradas de erro do hightlight
                $(element)
                    .closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error'); // definir a classe de erro no form-group
            },
            unhighlight: function (element) { // reverter a mudança feita pelo hightlight
                $(element)
                    .closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // definir a classe de erro no from-group
            }
        });
        return true;
      }
```

Comment: Como esta seu html? poderia postar aqui também?

Comment: <div class="col-md-11">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical" Height="80px" CssClass="form-control painelListOrigem">
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkLstOrigem" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox chkLstOrigem">
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <span class="require">*</span>
            </div>
        </div>